# Singleton Servlet Filter

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, singleton, servlet-filters

```
public class URLFilter implements Filter {

    private URLFilter() {
        //New instances are not permitted
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    }

}
```

Gives me the error:

> Class org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager can not access a
>   member of class com.example.singleton.URLFilter with modifiers
>   "private"

How else can I prevent multiple instances of servlet filters being created?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a singleton? A filter's lifecycle should be handled by the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you configure your filter with web.xml or annotations, then you need to provide a public, no args constructor for the container to instantiate it (Section 6.2 of Servlet Spec 3.1):

> The application developer creates a filter by implementing the 
>   javax.servlet.Filter interface and providing a public constructor taking no 
>   arguments

Section 6.2.1 also says:

> Only one instance per  declaration in the deployment descriptor is 
>   instantiated per JVM of the container

If you need finer control over filter instantiation, you need to use programmatic registration of the filter (See section 4.4.2 in [Servlet Specification 3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/servlet-3_1-final.pdf)).

Comment: See section 4.4.2 in [Servlet Specification 3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/servlet-3_1-final.pdf)